# Extracted bounding image is very small

Tags: python, image-processing, bounding-box

I have this code for detecting text on an image and bounding it by a green rectangle and extract each bounding text into a separate image, I have done this step but when it is generated and I try to open the image it is very small I cannot see it, I tried to apply resize but not works. please help me.

```
    img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
    copy = img.copy()
    ROI_number = 0

for detection in result: 
    top_left = tuple([int(val) for val in detection[0][0]])
    bottom_right = tuple([int(val) for val in detection[0][2]])
    #text = detection[2]
    #font= cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    img = cv2.rectangle(copy, top_left, bottom_right, (36,255,12), 2)
    ROI = copy[top_left, bottom_right]
    img2 = cv2.resize(ROI, dsize=(0,0), fx=5, fy=5)
    cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.jpg'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
    #img = cv2.putText(img,text,(20,spacer), font, 1,(0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    ROI_number += 1
#plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))    
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show
cv2.imshow('copy', copy)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your image is small because it is truly small.

But every decent image viewer has zoom that can zoom in and magnify your small image.

Your `resize` code is not working because you put `dim=(0,0)` , however it should be `None` in order `fx` and `fy` to work.

Comment: Thank you Lior for the reply, please explain more, as I'm new in the field of computer vision, I tried many image viewer and all same, they cannot display image